# Stationarity of Random Walk (Backshift Operator)

Tags: time-series, stationarity, random-walk

I have a question regarding the backshift operator.

A random walk $X_{t} = X_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}$ can be rewritten as $(1-B)X_{t} = \epsilon_{t}$.
We know that the first difference of a random walk is stationary, so using the backshift operator: $(1-B)^2X_{t} = (1-B)\epsilon_{t}$ should be stationary. However, this implies that there are 2 unit roots for $B=1$.

I do understand how it can be shown that a random walk in first differences in stationary, however, I struggle to show the absence of a unit root when using the backshift operator.

Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you think this implies "two unit roots" and in what sense a unit root might be "absent" from a process?  Indeed, what exactly do you mean by a "unit root for $B=1$"?

Comment: If we use the backshift operator, we can check for a unit root, if the roots of the equation $(1-B)^2=0$ are inside the unit circle (in absolute value). Therefore $B=1$ is a root on the unit circle, resp. 2 roots because of the square. But nevertheless, the process is not stationary, because there is a root to the euqation on the unit circle.
And by absent I mean that the equation has no root that lies inside the unit circle, i.e. is stationary, which is what I am trying to show here for a first differenced random walk (which is supposed to be stationary).